# Reusing Java Scanner

Tags: java, loops, input, integer

Ive written a small Java code to calculate the product of two integers input by the user using Scanner. The user is forced to input integer values. The code is shown below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x=0,y=0;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        //Asks for the first number until the user inputs an integer
        System.out.println("First number:");
        while(!sc.hasNextInt()){
            System.out.println("Not valid. First number:");
            sc.nextLine();
        }
        x=sc.nextInt();
        //Asks for the second number until the user inputs an integer
        System.out.println("Second number:");
        while(!sc.hasNextInt()){
            System.out.println("Not valid. Second number:");
            sc.nextLine();
        }
        y=sc.nextInt();
        //Show result
        System.out.println(x+"*"+y+"="+x*y);
    }
}
```

The loop for the first number works fine. But, the second doesn't: if the user inputs something that is not an integer value, the message "*Not valid. Second number:*" is shown twice!
**First number:

g

Not valid. First number:

2

Second number:

f

Not valid. Second number:

Not valid. Second number:

4

2*4=8**
What is the reason for this behaviour? I guess I'm doing something wrong.
I've tried to use two different Scanners (one for each number) and the problem dissapears, but I don't think that creating lots of instances is the correct path.
Can anybody help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because even after accepting the first int value there is still the newline character to consume,

so change to

```
x=sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: or reinitialize scanner like: x=sc.nextInt(); sc=new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: @RohitJain As per OP *I've tried to use two different Scanners (one for each number) and the problem dissapears*

Comment: @ScaryWombat Perfect! It works Great! So ... Is that like if I was reading the characters in a line but I left the "\n" and, then, the sc.nextLine() reads the "\n"??

Comment: @ScaryWombat By the way: I've tried to add 1 point to your answer but, due to my poor reputation, it has no effect  :( Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks @Krippulo

Comment: Yes, Done! (I'm a newbie on this)